# Combination of values , Based on corresponding values in a column

Tags: python-3.x, list, combinations, python-itertools

I have column named Volume which contains values like `[1.638, 0.625 , 5.001]` total values are 52000.

And `Part_Packing_Density` column which contains values like `[0.73, 0.20, 0.3]` total values are 52000.

Now the relation with two columns is described as , the packing density for volume 1.638 is 0.73 and for 0.625 is 0.20 and like wise for all values.

Generates all possible combinations of packing density values in such a way that the sum of the corresponding volume values is approximately equal to 40000.

For example:
`comb1 = [[0.73, 0.20, 0.3, 0.40]`

So, there respective values of volume are

`[1.638, 0.625 , 5.001, 44.621 ]`.

Now If I do addition of these values of volume like 1.638+0.625+5.00+44.621...+...+....  .

It should be approx. 40000.

I tried generating combinations in a single column , but that is not the end goal.

I want to have combinations based on corresponding values addition. Like I have explained above.

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: i would attempt to answer the question, but the question makes no sense...  where does 40000 come from ?

Comment: 40000 is the max limit of volume, i can have in my build.

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking for something on a similar note?

```
import itertools

volume = [1.638, 0.625, 5.001, 44.621]  
packing_density = [0.73, 0.20, 0.3, 0.40]  
target_sum = 40000
tolerance = 100  # deviation

def combinations_with_sum(data, target_sum, tolerance):
    for i in range(1, len(data) + 1):
        for comb in itertools.combinations(data, i):
            volume_sum = sum(volume[j] for j in range(len(data)) if packing_density[j] in comb)
            if abs(volume_sum - target_sum) <= tolerance:
                yield comb

result = list(combinations_with_sum(packing_density, target_sum, tolerance))
print(result)
```

Comment: No this code is not working, I have tried it.

Comment: this code returns and empty list.